# Facebook Video Call to action button

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-call-to-action

Is this future is for pages only? I don't see any such restriction in the [API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video), and when I try to make a post I see the video but not the action  button.

Here is the json that I send:

```
{
   "call_to_action":{
      "type":"INSTALL_MOBILE_APP",
      "value":{
         "link":"https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=com.my.app",
         "link_description":"My cool app",
         "link_title":"Download Now"
      }
   },
   "description":"Some description",
   "title":"Some title",
   "upload_phase":"finish",
   "upload_session_id":10204824944494400
}
```

How to add action button on my users wall?

Comment: That is only available for videos on pages, not user profiles. (When you compare the documentation for `/page/videos` and `/user/videos`, you’ll see that only the first one mentions call to action, the latter doesn’t.)

Comment: @CBroe tnx, I guess I didn't new how to read this.